# Netstat doesn't show my machine IP as listening on port 22

Tags: linux, netstat

I am able to ssh to the machine.
But my machine not shown as listening on port 22.
Below is what I see.
It show as listening on port 53, 21, 8080, 8443 etc. But no entry for 22(ssh).
My machine IP is 10.8.113.30. OS is windriver linux.
Why is this?

```
netstat -antu | grep LISTEN 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8083          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8084          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:8021        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:21          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3128            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:8443        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8123            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:8128        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8128          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25255         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5580            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5581            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:8080        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.8.113.30:81          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:81            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8021                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8128                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:18081         :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:81                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: It's listening on the IPv6 port 22.

Comment: On freebsd it used to show the exact IP address. Isn't that the case with linux? Exact IP address would really help. Anyway to get the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You machine is listening to port 22. Here's the line:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

The socket is listening for both IPv6 and IPv4 connections.

Comment: On freebsd it used to show the exact IP address. Isn't that the case with linux? Exact IP address would really help. Anyway to get the same?

Comment: A process can listen on a specific interface address, or it can use `INADDR_ANY` or `INADDR6_ANY`, which means is accepts connections on all interfaces. Linux by default listens on both IPV4 and IPv6 connections if `INADDR6_ANY` (`::`) is used.

Comment: My idea is to look for interfaces listening on port 22 and establish a ssh tunnel with tunnel server using a particular interface IP. So I am looking for IP address here.. In freebsd I see that we get this info with netstat command - netstat -na -p tcp -f inet | grep LISTEN. Anyways to get the IP on linux too? Also, pointing at your sentence ->  "Linux by default listens on both IPV4 and IPv6 connections if INADDR6_ANY (::) is used".. Is it safe to get the ip address from ifconfig's output and use this to establish tunnel as you say that linux by default listens on both IPV4/6"

Comment: To listen on a specific address only, you will have to configure the ssh server to listen to that address only. For example, you could put this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: `ListenAddress 10.8.113.30`. This forces the ssh server to only listen on that address.

Comment: @BRT: The point is that in this specific case the SSH daemon *is not listening on a specific address*; it's listening on *any* address. Poor `netstat` shows the truth.

Comment: You system will show the above line if it's listening on all ports (default). If you change your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to listen on one IPV4 address + disable IPV6 listening, then you'll likely see what you're after.